# Laravel 1 row missing while inserting and

Tags: laravel

```php
$purchase_line_datas = PurchaseLine::where('transaction_id', 
    $transaction->id)->get(); $i = 0; 
$input = [];

foreach ($purchase_line_datas as $key => $purchase_line_data) {
    if (!$enable_stock_transfer) {
        $qty_available = $this->productUtil->num_uf($purchases[$i]['quantity']);
    } else {
        $qty_available = 0;
    }
    
    $item = array(
        "business_id" => $business_id,
        "transaction_id" => $purchase_line_data->transaction_id,
        "purchase_line_id" => $purchase_line_data->id,
        "variation_id" => $purchase_line_data->variation_id,
        "contact_id" => $transaction_data['contact_id'],
        "product_id" => $purchase_line_data->product_id,
        "ref_no" => $ref_no,
        "new_barcode" => $purchase_line_data->barcode,
        "default_sell_price" => $this->productUtil->num_uf($purchases[$i]['default_sell_price']),
        "purchase_qty" => $this->productUtil->num_uf($purchases[$i]['quantity']),
        "qty_available" => $this->productUtil->num_uf($qty_available),
        "created_at" => Carbon::now()
    );
    array_push($input, $item);
    $i++;
}
ProductPurchaseSl::insert($input);
```

in this code I am inserting an array but after inserting.. it's showing that one row is missing.And it's happening very often.I couldn't be able to solve this problem.

Comment: i would suggest to log the number of items in $purchase_line_datas to see if the issue is with retrieving the PurchaseLines or with the inserts failing

Comment: no that's not the issue, I've already done that.but it's difficult to find out that way because it's not happening for all purchases. It's  happening sometimes for one or two.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it might skip any rows for any reason. Insert will insert everything, or nothing, I suppose.. Does it generate 1 or multiple SQL INSERT statements? You could look to see which queries are created and if any of them create errors...

In general, I think this will be hard to get good help on on stack overflow, because this is a debugging problem and the problem is likely outside of the code shown above.

Comment: yes it's generating multiple insert statements.